# Как попасть в корневую папку телефона?

Tags: java, android

Так открывается только недавние:

```
 public void onClick2(View view) {


        int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE=1;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("file/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно вместо этого:

```
intent.setType("file/*");
```

использовать это:

```
intent.setType("*/*");
```

думаю должно получится то что вы хотите. Напишите если не будет работать, тогда буду дальше искать и пробовать. Удачи :)

### UPDATE:

может так получится:

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()), "*/*");
```

### UPDATE_2:

вот еще один вариант есть:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CHOOSER = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create the ACTION_GET_CONTENT Intent
    Intent getContentIntent = FileUtils.createGetContentIntent();

    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(getContentIntent, "Select a file");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CHOOSER);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
     case REQUEST_CHOOSER: 
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

             final Uri uri = data.getData();

    // Get the File path from the Uri
             String path = FileUtils.getPath(this, uri);

    // Alternatively, use FileUtils.getFile(Context, Uri)
    if (path != null && FileUtils.isLocal(path)) {
     File file = new File(path);
    }
         }
   break;
    }
}
```

вот [первоисточник](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/157).

Comment: Нет к сожалению не работает

Comment: Так вылетает...

Comment: а что пишет при вылете?